# Automation on Windows: Launch/close of second app due to launch/close of first app

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation

I want to create an automation on Windows 10 where if I open the first app, I want to a second app (predetermined) to open up as well. And when I close the first app, the second app should close as well (*essentially, the start and end times of both apps should be the same*)

Not sure if there is a built-in function in Windows to do this, or is it something I have to code up myself?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No built in function for that. You might be able to fake it in Task Scheduler but not likely. So this is code your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **start** two or more programs through a batch file. For example, to start both Notepad and Notepad++, save the following in a file with extension *.bat* .

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
start "" "%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"
```

It is also possible to have application run in **sequence**, e.g., to open Notepad++ first, and on its close, then open Notepad., save the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
"%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"
```

However, the situation is a bit murky with having two apps run simultaneously, and having the end of one *close* another. Rather, I'd add a second batch file, using *taskkill /F /IM <app.exe>* to end each running app. Create two keyboard shortcuts to run each of the batch files, and you've automated starting and ending them.

Comment: Thank you! This is good solution for my problem!

Comment: @MrJeevs, Glad it might help. Mark the question if it *does* resolve the issue for you.